# How to Split a cell in JS API for MS365 excel labscript

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-js-helpers

I am trying to split a cell/string simply in MS365 using Labscript.

Split() or LEFT does not exist in Labscript which is another reason why I am not sure why MS claims that javascript is the language of use for Labscript.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realised that substr() works (or maybe even split). These commands do not show up as options though as you write the code unless the code is executed first and the string is verified as a string (I was reading a cell that I wanted to split).

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that substr() works (or maybe even split). These commands do not show up as options though as you write the code unless the code is executed first and the string is verified as a string (I was reading a cell that I wanted to split).